# Get Value from View Child Component (from Child to Parent)

Tags: angular

I have this code to my parent (profile.component.ts)

```
@ViewChild(QuestionComponent) questions: QuestionComponent;
```

then `console.log('questions');` return

[image]

I just want to get the questions value which the red highlighted box below . How can I do this?

Comment: Why are you fetching whole component `QuestionComponent`? simply get value using local variable

Comment: @PardeepJain you mean using somehthing like this @ViewChild('questions') questions: QuestionComponent;

Comment: Can you create stackblitz for the same? or post some relevant code of template

Comment: use questions['questions'] in your parent component after importing yopu child component with viewChild

Answer (score 0):

You can access the child component data in parent component using @ViewChild directive.

### In your parent component:

```
ParentClass implements OnInit{

  @ViewChild(QuestionComponent) questionComponent: QuestionComponent;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getQuestions(); // you can call this function wherever you need it
                         // just, for example, I am calling it from ngOnInit
  }

  getQuestions() {
    if (questionComponent) {
      console.log(questionComponent.questions); // like this way we can access child component variables and functions in parent class
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Note: This will work only if you are having only one QuestionComponent as a child

Comment: I'm getting undefined

Comment: Then in your child class, initialize the variable as questions = false;

Comment: I just found out that the data needs to delay since the child is still rendering , don't know if that's the issue

Comment: If you can provide your actual code, then only we can suggest anything